# How to solve "cycle detected when computing the supertrait"?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a trait `Component` with an associated type `Msg`:

```
trait Component {
    type Msg;
    fn update(&self, msg: Self::Msg);
}
```

I modified it to implement a clone:

```
trait Component: ComponentClone<Self::Msg> {
    type Msg;
    fn update(&self, msg: Self::Msg);
}

pub trait ComponentClone<T> {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Component<Msg = T>>;
}

impl<T, M> ComponentClone<M> for T
where
    T: 'static + Component<M> + Clone,
{
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Component<M>> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

impl<M: 'static> Clone for Box<dyn Component<M>> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<dyn Component<M>> {
        self.clone_box()
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3d347480d1375e9a504d26ad49c6a644)

I got an error:

```
error[E0391]: cycle detected when computing the supertraits of `Component`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:1
  |
1 | trait Component: ComponentClone<Self::Msg> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: ...which again requires computing the supertraits of `Component`, completing the cycle
note: cycle used when collecting item types in top-level module
 --> src/lib.rs:1:1
  |
1 | trait Component: ComponentClone<Self::Msg> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I try to use generics, everything compiles (but I do get warnings):

```
trait Component<M>: ComponentClone<M> {
    fn update(&self, msg: M);
}

pub trait ComponentClone<T> {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Component<T>>;
}

impl<T, M> ComponentClone<M> for T
where
    T: 'static + Component<M> + Clone,
{
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Component<M>> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

impl<M: 'static> Clone for Box<dyn Component<M>> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<dyn Component<M>> {
        self.clone_box()
    }
}
```

What's wrong? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `trait Component {…}` and `trait ComponentClone: Component {…}` instead of the reverse?

Answer (score 4):

*While the code given contains other errorrs I'll focus on the question in particular situation.*

When you have a trait bound which depends on an associated type in the trait being defined, provide a full path (aka UFCS) to the associated type:

```
trait Component: ComponentClone<<Self as Component>::Msg> {
    //                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use a full path to Msg
    type Msg;
    fn update(&self, msg: Self::Msg);
}

pub trait ComponentClone<T> {
    /* snip */
}
```

Related issue  [rust-lang/rust#62581 "Cycle computing supertraits" error could be more helpful #62581](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62581)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can get away by moving `Msg` into an own trait:

```
pub trait ComponentMsg {
    type Msg;
}

pub trait Component : ComponentClone + ComponentMsg {
    fn update(&self, msg: Self::Msg);
}

pub trait ComponentClone : ComponentMsg {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Component<Msg=Self::Msg>>;
}

impl<T, M> ComponentClone for T
where
    T: 'static + Component<Msg=M> + Clone,
{
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Component<Msg=M>> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

impl<M: 'static> Clone for Box<dyn Component<Msg=M>> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<dyn Component<Msg=M>> {
        self.clone_box()
    }
}
```